# why cant specify container name when using imperative cmd to create cronjob in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm trying to run a cmd to create cronjob:

```
"k create cronjob mycron --image:httpd --schedule="*/8 * * * *" --name=mycontainer-name"
```

but it does not recognize, i tried to use flag "--container-name=mycontainer-name" but not working too.

is there way to do 1 liner and specify container name in it? or the only way is to use declarative like

```
"k create cronjob mycron --image:httpd --schedule="*/8 * * * *" --dry-run=client -oyaml > d.yaml"
```

and then change it in yaml file and run apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think CLI supports any Options to name container. You can check kubectl create cronjob --help for all the available options.
kubectl apply seems to be the only possible way.

Comment: Txh for showing this simple way.. indeed there is no such option

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @TarunVerma's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597359/1121249). Here is current implementation of [kubectl create cronjob](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/b35935138f5330d299e89b1278b5738487e4f015/pkg/cmd/create/create_cronjob.go#L210C22-L210C22):

```golang
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{APIVersion: batchv1.SchemeGroupVersion.String(), Kind: "CronJob"},
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: o.Name,
        },
        Spec: batchv1.CronJobSpec{
            Schedule: o.Schedule,
            JobTemplate: batchv1.JobTemplateSpec{
                ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
                    Name: o.Name,
                },
                Spec: batchv1.JobSpec{
                    Template: corev1.PodTemplateSpec{
                        Spec: corev1.PodSpec{
                            Containers: []corev1.Container{
                                {
                                    Name:    o.Name,
                                    Image:   o.Image,
                                    Command: o.Command,
                                },
                            },
                            RestartPolicy: corev1.RestartPolicy(o.Restart),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

`o.Name` in code above is used for 1) name of cron job, 2) name in template and 3) **name of container** at same time. No way to specify it separately.

Comment: ok, why json format..

Comment: what json? this is snippet of [Go](https://go.dev/). This isn't even a valid json